# How to send messages to individual participants in a zoom meeting?

Tags: python, zoom-sdk

How would I send messages to individual participants in a Zoom meeting using Python?

- I couldn't find any libraries/modules that would solve this problem.
- I looked in the Zoom's API documentation and found only messaging system for the chat in Zoom client (but not for the in-meeting messaging).
- I could use `captions` like described in [this zoom article](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115002212983-Integrating-a-third-party-closed-captioning-service#h_fa0214f2-3a28-4fd1-addd-99659705fd49) (send captions via HTTP POST method). But the functionality is limited and you can't show messages to individual users, but only to everyone at once which is not intended.

Did I overlook something?
Is there any way to do this?

---

**Edit:**

I tried using Selenium but there are bunch of `Captchas` (as suggested in the comment by @piertoni) and password in the way. So I would like to avoid this solution.

Comment: If you are using a browser and you don't have better options, a way could be selenium.

Comment: We are using Zoom application for meetings.

Comment: Another option could be http://www.sikulix.com/ but is the last strand as is visual automation

Comment: Yeah I would like to avoid the GUI automation approach. Because I need also a way how to get all the users in a meeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this easily.  Here's a [recent thread](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/is-there-an-automated-way-to-send-a-private-message-to-a-participant-in-a-meeting/36562/5) that says it's not on the API roadmap.  Even with browser-based automation, you have seen that Zoom has anti-automation tools in place to prevent spam.  GUI automation as suggested in the comments would likely work.

If you have API access to the meeting, a Business account or higher, and want to do GUI automation, you can use [this route](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/dashboards/dashboardmeetingparticipants) to get meeting participants.

Comment: @Spacehold care to elaborate?  How is this false info?  You posted that and then posted an answer that just says what I said in my second sentence.

Comment: @Spacehold you deleted a comment that said "This is false info."  Btw, mods can see even deleted comments.

Comment: I deleted it because I rechecked it. I thought you were talking about this whole different sdk